# Não consigo posicionar lista

Tags: css

Galera não tô conseguindo posicionar a lista com id **sub1** usando css, a outra tá posicionando normal. Não tô conseguindo saber o por que, alguém pode me ajudar?

Segue o codigo:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Menu</title>
        <style>
            #menu{
                list-style:none;
                position:absolute;
                left:15%;
            }

            #menu li{
                display:inline;
                border:1px solid black;
                float:left;
                padding:10px;
                width:140px;
                text-align:center;
                background-color:#CCCCCC;
            }

            #menu li a{
                text-decoration:none;
                display:block;
                font-weight:bold;
                font-family:verdana;
            }



            <!--submenus-->


            #sub1{              
                position:absolute;
                left:15%;
                top:30%;
            }

            #sub1 li{
                list-style:none;
                border:1px solid black;
                width:140px;
                padding:10px;
                background-color:#CCCCCC;
                font-weight:bold;
                font-family:verdana;
            }

            #sub1 li a{
                text-decoration:none;
                display:block;

            }



        </style>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#menu1").hover(function(){
                    $(this).css("background-color" , "#EDEDED");
                },function(){
                    $(this).css("background-color" , "#CCCCCC");
                });


                $("#menu2").hover(function(){
                    $(this).css("background-color" , "#EDEDED");
                },function(){
                    $(this).css("background-color" , "#CCCCCC");
                });



                $("#menu3").hover(function(){
                    $(this).css("background-color" , "#EDEDED");
                },function(){
                    $(this).css("background-color" , "#CCCCCC");
                });



                $("#menu4").hover(function(){
                    $(this).css("background-color" , "#EDEDED");
                },function(){
                    $(this).css("background-color" , "#CCCCCC");
                });



                $("#menu5").hover(function(){
                    $(this).css("background-color" , "#EDEDED");
                },function(){
                    $(this).css("background-color" , "#CCCCCC");
                });             
            }); 


            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#opcao1").hover(function(){
                    $(this).css("background-color" , "#EDEDED");
                },function(){
                    $(this).css("background-color" , "#CCCCCC");

                });


                $("#opcao2").hover(function(){
                    $(this).css("background-color" , "#EDEDED");
                },function(){
                    $(this).css("background-color" , "#CCCCCC");

                });


                $("#opcao3").hover(function(){
                    $(this).css("background-color" , "#EDEDED");
                },function(){
                    $(this).css("background-color" , "#CCCCCC");

                });

            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul id="menu">
            <li id="menu1"><a href="">Menu1</a></li>
            <li id="menu2"><a href="">Menu2</a></li>
            <li id="menu3"><a href="" >Menu3</a></li>
            <li id="menu4"><a href="" >Menu4</a></li>
            <li id="menu5"><a href="">Menu5</a></li>
        </ul>


        <ul id="sub1">
            <li id="opcao1"><a href="">opcao1</a></li>
            <li id="opcao2"><a href="">opcao2</a></li>
            <li id="opcao3"><a href="" >opcao3</a></li>         
        </ul>

    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provavelmente é por causa do css dos submenus...

Tenta colocar cada #menu li -> position: relative

Depois disso, você ajusta cada submenu (position: absolute) com top e left.

**EDIT:**

Criei um exemplo funcionando no codepen pra você entender melhor:
http://codepen.io/Gabcoder/pen/oYwdZK

Dicas:

1. Use *classes* em vez de *id* quando houver repetição de css.
2. Atributos como text-decoration: none; são desnecessários, pois já são definidos assim por padrão.

Comment: tentei, nada aconteceu

Comment: Conseguiu? Se a resposta te ajudou, não se esqueça de avaliar ;)

Answer (score 1):

Se ele é um sub menu, ele deve ficar dentro do principal:

```
<body>
    <ul id="menu">
        <li id="menu1"><a href="">Menu1</a>
            <ul id="sub1">
                <li id="opcao1"><a href="">opcao1</a></li>
                <li id="opcao2"><a href="">opcao2</a></li>
                <li id="opcao3"><a href="" >opcao3</a></li>         
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="menu2"><a href="">Menu2</a></li>
        <li id="menu3"><a href="" >Menu3</a></li>
        <li id="menu4"><a href="" >Menu4</a></li>
        <li id="menu5"><a href="">Menu5</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
```